# Missing header 'amqp_consumerQueue' from RabbitMQ message

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have an application that reads RabbitMQ messages from a number of queues using Spring AMPQ and a RabbitListener. Something like this

```
@RabbitListener(queues = {"#{'${rabbit.queues}'.split(',')}"})
public void processRabbitMessage(@Payload String data, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue, @Header(AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId) throws Exception {
// Do some stuff
}
```

However I'm getting an intermittent error where the message header isn't set.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.service.RabbitService.processRabbitMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]
Bean [com.service.RabbitService@5b7a7f33]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'amqp_consumerQueue' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:100)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:103)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

All the messages are written to the queues in exactly the same way (as below) and come from the same source so are generally the same structure.

```
MessageProperties msgprop = new MessageProperties()
msgprop.setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
msgprop.setAppId(routing)

rabbitTemplate.send(exchange, routing, new Message(message.getBytes(), msgprop))
```

We're not loosing data since we can catch all the rejected messages in a DLX but it's difficult to reprocess when we don't know what queue they came from.

We know that none of the messages are null/malformed (even the ones generating errors) and I was under the impression that this was a header set by Rabbit based on the queue a message is written to so how can it be null?

Any ideas as to how this header is null for some and not all messages and/or a possible fix to insure the headers are set?

EDIT: Added some DEBUG logs of the last attempt at reading in the message. We have a stateless retry policy in place so it's tried twice already.

```
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=3
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry failed last attempt: count=3
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] WARN  o.s.a.r.r.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries exhausted for message (Body:'{Message:Body}' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=a.b-209491726, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=a.b, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=exch, receivedRoutingKey=a.b, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=561, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-fpVPl0EjHwdKew6eTEMoWA, consumerQueue=null])org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.service.RabbitService.processRabbitMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]Bean [com.service.RabbitService@5b7a7f33]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'amqp_consumerQueue' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:100)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:103)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.recover(RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.java:45)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean$1.recover(StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean.java:66)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean$1.recover(StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean.java:59)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$ItemRecovererCallback.recover(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:141)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:350)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.service.RabbitService.processRabbitMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]
Bean [com.service.RabbitService@5b7a7f33]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.service.RabbitService.processRabbitMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]
Bean [com.service.RabbitService@5b7a7f33]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'amqp_consumerQueue' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:100)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:103)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Rejecting messages (requeue=false)
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Cancelling Consumer@2f48a506: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://exch@1.1.1.1//exch,1055), conn: Proxy@79239726 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@7d1c1c5d [delegate=amqp://exch@10.136.229.112:5672//exch, localPort= 45298], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
00:46:17.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1051] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://exch@10.136.229.112:5672//exch,1055), conn: Proxy@79239726 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@7d1c1c5d [delegate=amqp://exch@10.136.229.112:5672//exch, localPort= 45298]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that's possible; we [unconditionally set the consumerQueue property in the received message](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/BlockingQueueConsumer.java#L412) - which is the source for that header. We maintain a map of consumerTag -> queue name for this purpose.

A DEBUG log for a message delivery that exhibits this behavior would be useful.

Comment: I've added some debug logs. Is there even a work around where I could manually force the setting of this header on the producer side? Thanks

Comment: That's not enough log; I need to see the message being delivered to the container. You can't set that particular header on the producer side, but you can add your own header. There is also a header (that **is** set by rabbitMQ) `amqp_receivedRoutingKey` which is the routing key the producer used. If you are using the default exchange, the key will contain the queue name.

Comment: We stumbled upon exactly the same use case where OCCASIONALLY and seemingly randomly, the ``amqp_consumerQueue`` header is missing in the received message. All other headers, including custom ones, are there. The Spring Rabbit library used is 1.7.12, plus RabbitMQ ``amqp-client`` of newer version 4.9.3. So far I have not figured out what can be removing or hiding that header as it IS as you said, unconditionally set by consumer code.

Comment: (...) The ``amqp_consumerTag`` header is there though, so the only explanation is that something happens to the consumer while message is being delivered. Either there has been a channel disconnect or something similar, though I still do not understand why then the message was not "stopped" earlier? Will change my code to rely on routing key, as it is the next best thing out there to determine the source queue.

Comment: Don't comment on nearly 3 year old answers; ask a new question and show your code and config.